# "Попугаи" по-английски в контексте измерения чего-либо

Tags: английский

В русском языке есть такое выражение: измерять что-то в "попугаях". А есть ли что-то подобное в английском языке?

Abstract points - не совсем то, хотя имеет похожую смысловую нагрузку.

Comment: По-моему этот вопрос стоит задавать в подсайтах про английский язык, а не про русский.

Comment: Вам на English language and usage.stackexchange. Они обожают такие вопросы.

Comment: проблема в том, что в разделе посвящённом английскому языку не поймут фразу про попугаев ))))

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Вам придется объяснить ее смысл

Comment: нет, мне объяснять её смысл не нужно, я его понимаю )))) а вот англоязычной аудитории - пожалуй